# How to know when IntentService is paused

Tags: java, android-service

I have an in-process IntentService that transforms and caches images on disk which are used by the Activity, it could take 5 minutes to run (depending on device). Meanwhile, the activity continues to run and show low res versions of images to the user UI.

My question is, if the user sends the Activity to the background, the service continues to run but at some point it appears to pause since the progress halts and does not continue until `IntentService` is restarted.  I have intercepted the IntentService `onDestroy()` but noticed that it's only called when the IntentService completes entirely.

I'm OK with Android pausing my `IntentService` if it needs to, but is there any way to know if it is paused?   I would like to know in order to 1) cancel (or change) the notification message and perform any clean up.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the pause is due to the CPU entering sleep mode, a few seconds after the screen goes blank. Your service needs to acquire a [WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) in order to keep the CPU running (and release it right before the service finishes, but not on the `onDestroy()` method, which is not guaranteed to run every time). There is no warning sign that the CPU is going to enter sleep mode though, no broadcast event or anything like that.

Comment: If I don't use a WakeLock, What happens to the paused IntentService when the CPU comes back to "life" ?  Is is restored? and pick up where it left off?

Comment: Yes, it is restored and picks up where it left off.